# Toggle <audio> src in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Anyone with more React.js time, would know how I could create a music player with an audio tag? I'm reassembling the component but the song's src doesn't change ... Only the first song that the component reloads ... I developed this logic, but I don't know if it's the best ...

```
export default function Header(){
  const catalog = [
    {
    name: 'michael jackson song',
    url: 'michaeljackson.mp3'
    },
    {
    name: 'madonna',
    url: 'madonna.mp3' },
    { 
    name: 'u2',
    url: 'u2.mp3'
    }
]

  const size = catalog.length;

  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);
  const [ principal, setPrincipal ] = useState(null);
  const audioRef = useRef();

 

 useEffect(() => {
  setIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * size));
},[])

useEffect(() => {
  setPrincipal(catalog[index]);
},[index]);

useEffect(()=>{
  if(index !== null ){
  audioRef.current.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      setIndex( prev => prev + 1 === size - 1 ? prev + 1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * size))})
  }
  },[])


  function handleBack(){
    if( index === 0) {
      setIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * size))
    } else {
      setIndex( prev => prev - 1);
    }
  }

  function handleNext(){
      setIndex( prev => prev + 1 === size - 1 ? prev + 1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * size))
  }

  return (
    <>
         { principal ? 
         <>
             <div>
                <button onClick={() => handleBack()}> back </button>
                <p>{principal.name}</p>
                <button onClick={() => handleNext()}> next </button>
             </div>
             <audio ref={audioRef} controls>
                <source src={principal.url}/> 
             </audio>
         </>
         : null }
  </> )
}
```

if anyone wants to test it, there are these two tracks that I put on my S3.

https://aleatorio.s3.amazonaws.com/slowdown.mp3

https://atracks.s3.amazonaws.com/Example+-+All+Night+(OUT+NOW).mp3

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer since it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

### The issue

The issue seems to be with your custom `addEventListener`; since that only gets called once, if the source changes, the listener handler never updates on the element

### The solution

In this case, I'd strongly recommend using the react way and directly binding the function to the element instead of trying to set the event listener manually.

```js
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const songs = ['https://atracks.s3.amazonaws.com/Example+-+All+Night+(OUT+NOW).mp3', 'https://aleatorio.s3.amazonaws.com/slowdown.mp3'];


function App({ songs = [] }) {
  const [activeSong, setActiveSong] = useState(songs.findIndex(() => true));
  
  const nextSong = () => {
    if (activeSong === songs.length - 1) {
      setActiveSong(0);
    } else {
      setActiveSong(activeSong + 1);
    }
  };
  
  const prevSong = () => {
    if (activeSong === 0) {
      setActiveSong(songs.length - 1);
    } else {
      setActiveSong(activeSong - 1);
    }
  };
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      {activeSong !== -1 && (
        <div>
          <div>
            Source: {songs[activeSong]}
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={prevSong}>prev</button>
            <button onClick={nextSong}>next</button>
          </div>
          <audio controls onEnded={nextSong} src={songs[activeSong]}>
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
          </audio>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App songs={songs} />, domContainer);
```

```css
audio {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Cool, Derek rocked !!! Do you have a bitcoin wallet? Let me give you some money

Comment: @Gabriel - I do not; but if you're still feeling generous, you could always donate to any open source project!

Comment: Make sure you accept my answer if it worked for you

Comment: You are a great guy, derek! Just a question, where would I put the
 "play ()" function so that it plays automatically after the user interacts with the DOM and the previous song ends?

Comment: Forgets! Just put autoPlay, which already works. It doesn't work when it doesn't touch the DOM, but if the user clicks on something, it already works! Thanks Derek

Comment: @Gabriel - make sure you accept the answer so others can see it was answered